# Is there any way to recover code from an arduino?

Tags: file-recovery

So I made this device for my car using an arduino. great, works almost perfect, only have minor debugging left to do. then my computer crashes the other day and I lost all my files because I never thought to back anything up. I've put at least 20 hours into writing this code and I really don't want to have to try and write the whole thing again from memory just for minor debugging. Is there any way I can lift the current version of the code that is still on the arduino and store it as a file on my computer? I'm using a mega2560 and a macbook pro.

Answer (score 0):

At best you may be able to read out the machine code from the Atmel device.

You'd then need to use a dissembler / de-compiler  to convert the code to asm / c.

Working with the disassembled code won't be easy.

You won't get the original names for your constants / functions / subroutines, just arbitrarily assigned labels eg `sub1`

To be honest it'd probably be quicker to start over.

**Edit**

If it were me I'd whip the HDD out of the mac and throw it at the mercy of some decent data recovery software,

Good luck